# Copy Row From Table A to Table B Where Key Doesn't Exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO Master (Case)
SELECT Case
FROM Extract
WHERE (NOT Exists (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case))
GROUP BY Case;
```

I have two tables, Master and Extract, both have Case as their unique key.

I want to copy all rows from Extract to Master that don't appear in Master, so any row with a Case number that isn't in Master.

Hope that makes sense.

When I run my query it says Enter Parameter Value for Master.Case

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use column name in bracket [] i.e. [Case]. because its reserved word in sql for CASE WHEN.

```
            insert into .Master([Case]) 
            select distinct [Case] from Extract where [Case] NOT IN(select [Case] from Master);

            OR

            insert into Master([Case]) 
            select distinct [Case] from Extract t1 where NOT EXISTS(select [Case] from Master t2 where t1.[Case]=t2.[Case]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Master] ([Case])
SELECT [Case]
FROM [Extract]
WHERE NOT Exists (SELECT 1 FROM [Extract] WHERE [dbo].[Master].[Case] = [dbo]. 
[Extract].[Case])
GROUP BY [Case]
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error:  Invalid use of '.','!' or '()'. in query expression '[Master].[Case] = [Extract].[Case'.